# How we can create admin grid using block (without using UiComponent)?

Tags: grid, magento2.2.3

How we can create admin grid using block (without using UiComponent)?

Answer (score 3):

**step 1** In your controller first call your block to create tabs like this

```
    <?php

namespace vendor\module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class Ordersgridtable extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory = false;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Status'));
        $this->_addContent($this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Ordersgrid\Ordersgridtable'));
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }


}
```

**Step 2** create block for tabs like this

```
    <?php

namespace vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Ordersgrid;

class Ordersgridtable extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('hello_tabs');
        $this->setDestElementId('edit_form');
        $this->setTitle(__('Your Title'));
    }

    /**
     * Prepare Layout
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        $this->addTab(
            'abcd',
            [
                'label' => __('ABCD'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('sampleprocessing/order/grid', ['_current' => true]),
                'class' => 'ajax'
            ]
        );
        $this->addTab(
            'EFg',
            [
                'label' => __('EFg'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('hello/*/grid', ['_current' => true]),
                'class' => 'ajax'
            ]
        );
        $this->addTab(
            'hij',
            [
                'label' => __('hij'),
                'url' => $this->getUrl('hello/*/grid', ['_current' => true]),
                'class' => 'ajax'
            ]
        );
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

}
```

**Step 3** create another controller to call grid block (called from this tab block file) like this and setBody to that grid block

```
    <?php

namespace vendor\module\Controller\Adminhtml\Order;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\LayoutFactory
     */
    protected $resultLayoutFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->_view->getLayout()->createBlock('Vendor\Module\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid')->toHtml());
    }
}
```

**Step 4** Now create block that is called from this controller to create grid like this

```
 <?php

namespace  vendor\module\Block\Adminhtml\Ordersgrid;

class Grid extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Extended
{
    protected $productFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Backend\Helper\Data $backendHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        parent::__construct($context, $backendHelper, $data);
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setId('hello_tab_grid');
        $this->setDefaultSort('entity_id');
        $this->setUseAjax(true);
    }

    /**
     * @return Grid
     */
    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = $this->productFactory->create()->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect("*");
        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return parent::_prepareCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Extended
     */
    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('Product Id'),
                'sortable' => true,
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Product Name'),
                'index' => 'name'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'sku',
            [
                'header' => __('Sku'),
                'index' => 'sku'
            ]
        );

        return parent::_prepareColumns();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('hello/*/helloGrid', ['_current' => true]);
    }

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: In 3rd step you have used createBlock('TM\Tilemountain\Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid')->toHtml(). What is 'TM/Tilemountain'? Is it typo mistake?

Comment: apologies that typo mistake i have edited my answer that just vendorname/modulename/Block\Adminhtml\Grid\Grid'

Answer (score 1):

You can create Admin Grid using Layout.

**Step 1: Create block for this grid**

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Adminhtml/Post.php

```
<?php
  namespace Mageplaza\HelloWorld\Block\Adminhtml;

  class Post extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container
  {
     protected function _construct()
     {      
       YOUR CODE GOES HERE.
     }
  }
```

**Step 2: Create layout file**

Now we will need a layout file to connect with Grid Block and render the grid. Let’s create this file:

> app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/layout/Namespace_ModuleName_post_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <update handle="styles"/>
     <body>
       <referenceContainer name="content">
       </referenceContainer>
     </body>
 </page>
```

**Step 3: Add Column**

The Column set will define the columns which will be display in the grid. If you want to use massAction, you can add this block to the grid element:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Massaction" name="namespace.modulename.massaction" as="grid.massaction">
<arguments>
    <argument name="massaction_id_field" xsi:type="string">post_id</argument>
    <argument name="form_field_name" xsi:type="string">ids</argument>
    <argument name="use_select_all" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
    <argument name="options" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="disable" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/massDelete</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</arguments>
```

Comment: may i know how to  show a label for multiple value  shown in admin  grid column https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295585/how-to-show-a-label-in-admin-grid-in-magento-2/295587#295587 can you please  help for me to solve issue