# how to show a label in admin grid in magento 2

Tags: magento2, grid

grid using block (.xml file)

```
 <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" 
   as="customer_group">
   <arguments>
         <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer 
         Groups</argument>
         <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customer_group</argument>
    </arguments>
 </block>
```

[image]

Comment: customer_group column has ids, you want to show names right?

Comment: ya i want to show a  customer_group name and  stores name in the coulmn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the column class into your custom class:

```
<block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column" 
   as="customer_group">
   <arguments>
         <argument name="header" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Customer 
         Groups</argument>
         <argument name="index" xsi:type="string">customer_group</argument>
         <argument name="type" xsi:type="string">options</argument>
         <argument name="renderer" xsi:type="string">Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Columns\Modifier\CustomerGroup</argument>
    </arguments>
 </block>
```

> Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Columns\Modifier\CustomerGroup.php

```
<?php 
namespace Vendor\Module\Ui\DataProvider\Columns\Modifier; 
 
class CustomerGroup extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
        array $data = array()
    )
    {
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
 
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $groupIds = explode(',', $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
        $result = '';
        foreach ($groupIds as $key => $groupId) {
            $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($groupId);
            $result .= $group->getCode().',';
        }
        return rtrim($result, ',');
    }
}
```

Hope this will help you. Not tested. Please retrieve exact data.
Use same scenario for store column

**Update For payment method title**

Get payment method title from below code:

```
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scope,
        array $data = array()
    )
    {
        $this->scope = $scope;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    
    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $paymentMethods = explode(',', $row->getData($this->getColumn()->getIndex()));
        $methodList     = $this->scope->getValue('payment');
        $result = '';
        foreach ($paymentMethods as $method) {
            $result .= $methodList[$method]['title'].',';
        }
        return rtrim($result, ',');
    }
```

Comment: it reflects a error Object DOMDocument should be created.";i:1;s:8026:"#0 D:\wamp64\www\m2\magento\vendor\magento\framework\View\Element\UiComponent\Config\Reader.php

Comment: Will check and let you know @divyasekar

Comment: Are you using ui_component for creating grid?

Comment: no, i use a block to create  admin grid like https://www.magebay.com/docs/how-to-create-admin-grid-in-magento-2-using-layout/

Comment: Ok, Try to create a grid using ui_component, it is more easy to customize. If you need same for store let me know

Comment: i will try with ui-component, if any issue happens i will tell u

Comment: @divyasekar okay...:)

Comment: i was tried with ui component  its reflects a error with admin form. is there any way  to  show label in   block grid

Comment: Actually I Updated answer yesterday before `try ui_component method` comment, Just not noticed I forgot to let you know..Check with this answer and I will update Ui_component method link

Comment: thank you its working fine.

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: sorry to disturbing  you again, is there any way to  show a payment method name in grid i just tried by `\Magento\Payment\Api\Data\PaymentMethodInterface` but it not  works

Comment: Is it urgent?...Because I suppose to leave. Will help you tmrw?

Comment: its not urgent. u will help on tmrw thank you

Comment: What you getting in that column right now?

Comment: now i m geting a payment  method value https://prnt.sc/pxpgj4 https://prnt.sc/pxph3r

Comment: Save payment method name in data base.... Is payment code required for any other process?

Comment: i need a payment code for  payment restriction functionality

Comment: @divyasekar Got solution?

Comment: No i didn`t get any solution

Comment: I have updated please check.

Comment: its working thank u so much

Comment: Nope.....@divya

Answer (score 0):

if you want to change the column label for some grid in the backend (for example - customer groups grid).
Create:

> Vendor/Module/view/adminhtml/ui_component/customer_group_listing.xml

with the code of the column that you need to change, for example: customer_group_code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <columns name="customer_group_columns">
        <column name="customer_group_code">
            <settings>
                <filter>text</filter>
                <label translate="true">MY CUSTOM LABEL</label>
            </settings>
        </column>
</listing>
```

and run `setup:di:compile` and cache clean and flush.

Or if you want to show label instead of the numbers, you should use prepareDataSource function that extends `Magento\Customer\Ui\Component\Listing\Column`

If you need a special grid, write a comment on which grid do you want to change, I`ll help you.